# Заполнение таблицы предыдущими значениями

Tags: sql

Имеется таблица в 3 столбца: `id_client`, `source`, `click_time`.

В столбцах `source` и `click_time` могут отсутствовать значения, необходимо на место пропусков записать последнее значение по времени, причем начинать надо со столбца `click_time`, т.е. для таблицы:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q9FRz.png]

Должны быть вот такая табл.:

```
id_client     source     click_time
        1          a             01
        2          b             02
        1          b             03
        2          b             03
        3          c             04
        2          b             02
```

Comment: Функция LAG() спасёт отца русской демократии.